# Power series derivative

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

this is a problem that's bugging me. It's a two part question. I believe I have answered part a. I'm not sure where to start for part b, please help. I will upload the question also the answer for part a. I like the way you have answered my question earlier that's why I'm coming back to you. Thank you for all your helpcenter image description here[image][image]

Comment: You can swap differentiation and summation as the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: "help please" should not be part of the title. Imagine if every question had "help please" in its title........

Comment: There are two similar topics: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891715/find-the-derivative-gx-f-x-help-please/1891723?noredirect=1#comment3879715_1891723

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1891715/338955

Answer (score 0):

Part a) is correct. The center of the power series is $2$ and its radius of convergence is $3$.

As regard part b), you should know that, for power series, in order to compute the derivative in the interval $(-1,5)$, you can take the derivative term by term (see the section Differentiation and integration [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series)). Hence
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{3^n}(x-2)^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{3^{n+1}}(x-2)^{n}$$
The radius of convergence of $f'$ is the same one of $f$, that is $3$ (check it!).

Comment: Just figured it out i wasn't getting n^2/3n, I realized I wasn't bringing my n down when taking the derivative of (x-2)^n. That was my mistake. Thanks again.